# ansible.inventory.manager check inventory for error in python

Tags: python, api, ansible, ansible-inventory, inventory

I have an Ansible hosts.ini with an error

```
[linux]
server01 pr_ip_address = 10.0.0.1
```

I wrote following function in python

```
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader

def check_inventory():
    loader = DataLoader()
    InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources='hosts.ini')

check_inventory()
```

I'm trying to use the following messages as stderr :

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse
/inventories/hosts.ini  
with script plugin: problem running
/hosts.ini  
--list ([Errno 8] Exec format error: '/hosts.ini')
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse
/hosts.ini  
with ini plugin: /hosts.ini:913: Expected key=value host variable assignment, got:
pr_ip_address
[WARNING]: Unable to parse
/hosts.ini  
as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
```

My problem, I don't know to grab it and can't write it to stderr  or stdout.

When my ini-file is right like:

```
[linux]
server01 pr_ip_address=10.0.0.1
```

I get nothing back.... I thought I can use it for a try except or if else condition, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem. I Use ansible_runner and capture the Output of it. this works well for me :). Maybe it helps someone else too!

```
import os
import sys
import ansible_runner
from io import StringIO 
from termcolor import colored, cprint


def verify(inipath):
    class Capturing(list):
        def __enter__(self):
            self._stdout = sys.stdout
            sys.stdout = self._stringio = StringIO()
            return self
        def __exit__(self, *args):
            self.extend(self._stringio.getvalue().splitlines())
            del self._stringio    # free up some memory
            sys.stdout = self._stdout

    with Capturing() as output:
        r = ansible_runner.run(private_data_dir=inipath, 
                            inventory='hosts.ini', 
                            host_pattern='localhost', 
                            module='shell', 
                            module_args='whoami')
        print(r.status, str)


    def words_in_string(word_list, a_string):
        return set(word_list).intersection(a_string.split())

    error_handling = ['error', 'Failed', 'Errno']

    if words_in_string(error_handling, str(output)):
        print(output)
        cprint('something went wrong with your hosts.ini :(', 'green')
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        cprint('hosts.ini verify was successfully!!!', 'green')
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    verify(inipath='./')
```

Answer (score 0):

An Alternate Approach to the same:-

```
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader

def check_inventory():
    loader = DataLoader()
    inventory_obj = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=None, parse=True)
    valid_inventory = inventory_obj.parse_source(source='hosts.ini')

    if valid_inventory:
        return True
    return False

validate_inventory = check_inventory()

if validate_inventory:
    print('hosts.ini verification was successful!')
else:
    print('something went wrong with your hosts.ini inventory')
```